# XElement parsing from XDocument, far below, repeated 2

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I asked the same question yesterday.
I solved it beautifully by the help of a nice person.

Now, I have found that I lost one item.
I'd like to make like this;

```
1  Boo1    //  "1" is from <sdl:seg id="1">
2  Boo2
3  Boo3
...
..
.
```

From here.

```
<xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0">
  <sdl:seg-defs>
      <sdl:seg id="1">
           <sdl:value key="Hash">Foo1</sdl:value>
           <sdl:value key="Created">Boo1</sdl:value>
```

I'm trying to make like this..

```
XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Load(myPath);
Dictionary<string, XElement> myDic = myDoc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "seg")
    .Select((myValue, myKey) => new { myKey, myValue })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("id").Value, x => x);   // Error at .Attribute(  
List<string> myList = myDic
    .Where(x => ((x.Value).Name.LocalName == "value") 
             && ((string)(x.Value).Attribute("key") == "Created"))
    .Select(x.Key + "  " + (string)x.Value);
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", myList));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var q = from elem in myDoc.Descendants()
        where elem.Name.LocalName == "seg"
        from sub in elem.Descendants()
        where sub.Name.LocalName == "value" && sub.Attribute("key").Value == "Created"
        select new
        {
            Id = elem.Attribute("id").Value,
            Created = sub.Value
        };
```

with proper namespace handling:

```
XNamespace sdl = "http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0";
var q = from elem in myDoc.Descendants()
        where elem.Name == sdl + "seg"
        from sub in elem.Descendants()
        where sub.Name== sdl + "value" && sub.Attribute("key").Value == "Created"
        select new
        {
            Id = elem.Attribute("id").Value,
            Created = sub.Value
        };
```

ANd to format it:

```
        var msg = String.Join("\n", q.Select(item => $"{item.Id}   {item.Created}"));
```

Comment: XNamespace... I really appreciated. again.

Comment: I am happy to hear that. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            Dictionary<string, List<XElement>> myDic = myDoc.Descendants()  
                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "seg")
                .GroupBy(myKey => (string)myKey.Attribute("id"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Descendants().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "value").ToList());

            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> myDic2 = myDoc.Descendants()
                 .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "seg")
                 .GroupBy(myKey => (string)myKey.Attribute("id"))
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Descendants().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "value")
                    .GroupBy(z => (string)z.Attribute("key"), a => (string)a)
                    .ToDictionary(z => z.Key, a => a.FirstOrDefault()));
```

Comment: Found typos.  Also gave a 2nd solution.

Comment: Woooo. That is Brilliant !!  Thanks for your effort, energy and (most importantly) Time !!  Working well !!

Comment: Which solution? 1 or 2.

Comment: What do you mean "1" and "2" ? The whole comment you made. I used "myDic" and "myDic2" continuously.

Comment: Ah.. You mean "1" previous one, "2" corrected one. Of course the newer one (previous one was not working.)

Comment: Thanks.. for your help.

Comment: Meant Dict and Dict2.

Comment: Yep, I just looking into Dic2. That is amazing.. .How did you make it ? Are you a kind of Alien ?  amazing...

Comment: I've been using nested dictionary's for a few years.  Took me a while to get it working the first time, but now much easier.

Comment: Oh. You are the one who told me the first answer. Do you mind if I ask you another one ? Actually, I've tried it using classic "for" loops. But, I have not much knowledge about XElements. I cound not make a nested search. Can you give me a hint ? I am planning to post the same question sometime later. Thanks anyways..........

Comment: Do you know the difference between Elements() and Descendants()?  Once you get the Elements in 1st for loop and 2nd for loop may need to use descendants.  Elements only work for children of an Element.  Grandchildren must use Descendants.